# Ajax success function not working: Django JSONResponse not sending

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

In the code below, I am using onclick (I know it may not be the best practice but for my particular situation I think it works best) to activate an ajax call to dynamically update the content on my Django template. As of now, the data is going to the back-end, and the Comment object is being created.

However, when returning a JSONResponse, the template is not using the data from this JSONResponse to update the page in any way. I have tried testing with alerts but to no avail. I am new to JS so I would love a little help! Thank you very much.

Django View:

```
def sochome(request, oid):
    society = Society.objects.filter(id=oid).first()
    membership = SocietyMembership.objects.get(member=request.user, society=society)
    response_data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postID = request.POST.get('post_id')
        comment_content = request.POST.get('comment')
        response_data['post_id'] = postID
        response_data['comment'] = comment_content
        post = SocPost.objects.filter(id=postID).first()
        SocComment.objects.create(post=post, author=request.user, content=comment_content)
        # print(response_data, file=sys.stderr)
        # print("SUCCESS JSON RESPONSE TO CLIENT SIDE", file=sys.stderr)
        return JsonResponse(response_data)

    context = {
        'membership': membership,
        'posts': society.posts.all().order_by('-date_posted')
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/sochome.html', context)
```

HTML:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function update_comment(post_id) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "{% url 'blog-sochome' oid=membership.society.id%}",
      data: {
        'post_id': post_id,
        'comment': document.getElementById(post_id.toString()).value
      },
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(data) {
        alert("ajax completed ");
      }
    });
  } <
  /script>
```

```html
<div id="{{post.id}}-comment-section" class="mb-3 pr-5 pt-4 pb-2 bg-light shadow-sm border-light" style="border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem; border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;">
  <div class="col-sm-12 pl-5 pb-5">
    <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="" style="display:flex" id="comment"> {% csrf_token %}
      <input id="{{post.id}}" type="search" name="comment" placeholder="New comment" class="form-control mr-sm-2 p-4" style="flex-grow:1;">
      <button name="post_id" class="btn btn-info my-2 my-sm-0 " value="{{post.id}}" onclick="update_comment({{post.id}})"> Post </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  {% for comment in post.comments.all %}

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1 offset-1 pl-4">
      <img class="rounded-circle comment-image" src="{{ comment.author.profile.image.url }}" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a class="mr-2 comment-author-name" href="#">{{ comment.author.first_name }} {{ comment.author.last_name }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted comment-time"><br>{{ comment.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 offset-1">
      <p class="comment-content">{{ comment.content }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  {% empty %}
  <div class="px-5">
    <p>No comments for this post.</p>
  </div>

  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You aren't preventing the default form submit process so the page is going to reload as a result

Comment: hi @charlietfl the page isnt reloading at all, it's instead directing me to a blank page with the JSON content. Any ideas on how to direct it to the same page, or how to use preventDefault to stop the reload? Again, I'm quite new.

Comment: So do some research into how to use `preventDefault`. You are already on the right path knowing it exists. Research is a significant part of learning to code.

Comment: I have been researching for a day or two now, but it is not about the reload, that is not my issue. The issue is, the success function isn't working and my browser is displaying raw JSON data. That means that the ajax call itself is working in order to send it to the backend but its not processing it or receiving it on client side again. I need help with this aspect first.

Comment: That's because the endpoint you submit to with the form is responding with json. It is the same problem. You want the ajax to receive the json not to reload browser with it by submitting the form. Preventing the form submit process is first place to start

Comment: I see how I was wrong, thank you so much! It makes perfect sense, I'll go ahead and learn how to prevent the reload with preventDefault in the right notation. Thank you again Charlie! Much appreciated.